# DBpedia subclasses of ship

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, dbpedia

I have a simple question about DBpedia. I want to get all the subclasses of [Ship](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Ship). I've tried with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?type WHERE {
  ?type rdfs:subClassOf dbpedia-owl:Ship
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Ftype+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++++%3Ftype+rdfs%3AsubClassOf+dbpedia-owl%3AShip%0D%0A++++%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The result is empty.  If I try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?type ?y WHERE {
  ?type ?y dbpedia-owl:Ship
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Ftype+%3Fy+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++++%3Ftype+%3Fy+dbpedia-owl%3AShip%0D%0A++++%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

I get the subclasses, but I don't understand why the first query does not work.

Comment: What subclasses do you get in the second query?  I ran the same query (there's a link to the results in my answer) and most of the results are instances of `Ship`, but I don't see any subclasses.

Answer (score 3):

I do not see any subclasses in the results of your second query.  It looks like most of the bindings for `?y` are `rdf:type`.  Indeed, the following query returns just two results.

```
SELECT distinct ?y WHERE {
  ?type ?y dbpedia-owl:Ship
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++SELECT+distinct+%3Fy+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++++%3Ftype+%3Fy+dbpedia-owl%3AShip%0D%0A++++%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
y
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type
http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#domain
```

The DBpedia ontology does not have any subclasses of `Ship`.  You can [browse the ontology](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/), and you'll see that `Ship`, along with some other classes, are subclasses of `MeanOfTransportation`, but none of these have subclasses.

Comment: Thank you! You have clarified my doubt.

Comment: @user2509954 Glad to have helped, and welcome to StackOverflow!  If this answer suits your needs, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/225437) to let other users know that it worked for you (and to reward the answerer with a bit of reputation)!  Happy SPARQL'ing!